# Neck hunchbacked: How do I straighten it?

Tags: workout-routines, neck

Today, I noticed that my my neck appears to have a small hunchback.  Do you know workouts that could improve my neck posture in order to straighten it?  Additionally, my bed is orthopedic and I have a soft pillow.  I think the way I sleep and my soft pillow may be a cause.

Answer (score 3):

Thoracic Kyphosis and Forward Head ("Computer Guy" Hunchback): Upper cross syndrome is another posture issue caused by sitting while hunching forward (at a computer, over books, etc).

Pectorals and the upper back/next tend to be tight as a result and the scapular muscles (shoulder blades) and neck flexors tend to be weak. [This post](http://www.reddit.com/r/Fitness/comments/exgiu/a_guide_to_fixing_computer_guy_posture_upper_body/) has excellent information on why you're doing different exercises, but many of the links have degraded.

[This pdf](http://kaasplateau.com/stretches.pdf) demonstrates how to do the specific exercises mentioned (skip to page 4 for the specifics for this section, although all of the stretches are good).

[image]

Source: reddit.com/r/fitness

Answer (score -5):

The spine is nothing to take lightly. If it's a question about the spinal column I always say get a professional to look at it in person.

Answer (score -5):

This is a common problem for most of the IT guys as well as heavy social media users on mobile. I got this problem a month back I tried some good Yoga Pose suggested by Baba Ramdev( India). It helped me a lot. You can search for his reference in Google.